# Safe max line length for Minified javascript on Win7?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-7, minifiedjs

I am seeing following error on Win 7: 'line 1 col 26270 access is denied'

Is there any doc regarding what would be a good chars-per-line limit for minified javascrpt? I am currently using 50k and it looks like a bad idea for Windows. Also this JS file is from a page inside iframe, not sure if there's any special rules for iframe pages that don't apply to the host page.

This error is not happening on Windows 8 and OSX, only showing up for Win 7.

Comment: Mainstream JavaScript engines don't care and treat a non-literal newline the same as a space with the addition of ASI rules, nothing more. And since I won't be looking at such a mess, I don't care either - the *title* opinion question otherwise, make sure to present the real problem from the start.

Comment: It's very very unlikely that the cause of the error is the long line. Try the code unminified.